# Button background before a thread

Tags: android

Why the background of the button doesn't change before the thread starts? It changes after the thread sleep ends. I mention that the background changes if there is no thread.

```
answer1Top.setBackgroundDrawable(correct);
try {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

 //I want to stop this
 playerScTop--;
 playerScoreTop.setText(String.valueOf(playerScTop));
```

Comment: Don't `sleep()` in the UI thread and don't update UI components off the UI thread. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i want to set a background for 2 seconds and then i want to set another background, after thread sleep time expires

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new class extending `AsyncTask`, pass it the `View` of which to change the background as well as the two background `Drawable` instances, then:

- in `onPreExecute()` (runs on UI thread), set the first background drawable on your view
- in `doInBackground()` (runs on background thread), sleep 2 seconds
- in `onPostExecute()` (runs on UI thread), set the other drawable on your view

Untested sample code:

```
public class BackgroundChangeTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private View view;
    private Drawable background1;
    private Drawable background2;

    public BackgroundChangeTask(View view, Drawable background1, Drawable background2) {
        this.view = view;
        this.background1 = background1;
        this.background2 = background2;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        view.setBackgroundDrawable(background1);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // too bad
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        view.setBackgroundDrawable(background2);

        // add anything else you want to run "after 2 seconds" here, e.g.
        playerScTop--;
        playerScoreTop.setText(String.valueOf(playerScTop));
    }
}
```

Invoke from your Activity/Fragment/etc like this (*no need* to keep the created task around in a field):

```
new BackgroundChangeTask(BackgroundChangeTask, correct, theOtherDrawable).execute();
```

Comment: but i think this will not stop my code for 2 seconds. i think this will run in background. am i right?

Comment: Yes, because you don't want to block the UI thread at all, even less so for 2 seconds. Android might force close your app for that.

Comment: You didn't mention you wanted to "stop your code" in your question -- if you want to, you need to be more specific about what exactly you want to stop, and it better not be the UI thread :)

Comment: but if i put this   try {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} in fornt of this    new BackgroundChangeTask(BackgroundChangeTask, correct, theOtherDrawable).execute();

Comment: I updated my answer: Just put the code to run "after 2 seconds" into `onPostExecute()` -- if you keep `BackgroundChangeTask` as inner class  of your Activity, you can access all its fields without passing lots of constructor arguments.

Comment: @Philipp Reichart +1 Awesome answer, Helped me alot. It reduces my efforts..thanks again..Cool

Comment: @Venky You should check out HandlerExplot's answer, his approach is much more elegant and shorter :)

Answer (score 2):

```
answer1Top.setBackgroundDrawable(correct);

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

     @Override
     public void run() {
          playerScTop--;
          playerScoreTop.setText(String.valueOf(playerScTop));
     }

}, 2000);
```

Comment: Much more elegant than my approach :)

Comment: @Alex Seeing you accepted my answer, I would really recommend this answer over mine. It's much more elegant and shorter.